# Button doesn't update in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

When it's used in Chrome or Safari it works just fine, but in Internet Explorer it doesn't work. In Chrome the button changes almost instantly when you click it. But when you click the button in IE, the status changes (in database), but it is not displayed. When you refresh the page (F5), then you see the button changed.

Now I found another problem in Internet Explorer. In older versions only the first button loads. Then the other buttons don't get displayed. Of course it does work in other browsers.

I created a div on the page, where the button is created. And then use te following script:

```
// JavaScript Document
function checkStatus( data, user ) {
    var result = null, scriptUrl = "../../templates/template/php/status.php?data="+data+"&user="+user;
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: scriptUrl,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            result = data;
        }
    });
    return result;
}

function setButton(data, user) {
    var status = checkStatus(data, user);
    if (status==='1') {
        jQuery( "#button" + data ).removeClass( "btn-primary" ).removeClass( "btn-danger" ).addClass( "btn-success" ).attr('value', 'aanwezig');
    }
    if (status==='0') {
        jQuery( "#button" + data ).removeClass( "btn-primary" ).removeClass( "btn-success" ).addClass( "btn-danger" ).attr('value', 'afwezig');
    }
}

function changeStatus( data, user ) {
    var status = checkStatus( data, user );
    if ( status==='1' ) {
        //afmelden
        var scriptUrl = "../../templates/template/php/afmelden.php?data=" + data +"&user="+user;
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: scriptUrl,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            async: false,
            success: function() {
                setButton(data, user);
            }
        });
    }
    if (status==='0') {
        //aanmelden
        var scriptUrl = "../../templates/template/php/aanmelden.php?data=" + data + "&user="+user;
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: scriptUrl,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            async: false,
            success: function() {
                setButton(data, user);
            }
        });
    }
}

function showButton( data, user ) {
    //set a button
    jQuery( "#" + data ).replaceWith( "<input type='submit' value='none' class='btn btn-primary' id='button" + data + "' />");
    setButton(data, user);
    jQuery("#button" + data).click(function() {
        changeStatus(data, user);
    });
}
```

Comment: IE does not play well with jQuery, AJAX, or CSS.  It's most likely the browser, not your code since it works in the other browsers.  There are workarounds to make IE work with jQuery though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are experiencing an ajax caching issues in IE.

You can disable ajax caching since you are using Jquery by doing the following:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

or disable per request

```
$.ajax({
  cache: false,
  //other options...
});
```

This website has some other alternatives to help you as well

http://www.itworld.com/article/2693447/development/ajax-requests-not-executing-or-updating-in-internet-explorer---solution.html